# How can I define a task named with a hyphen?

Tags: java, ant

**build.xml**

```
<taskdef
   onerror  ="ignore"
   name     ="monitor-client"
   classpath="${jar-client}"
   classname="hpms.app.mon.client.AntTask" />

<target name="run-client" depends="compile-sample" description="Launch monitor">
   <monitor-client
      layout      ="Layout.xml"
      gui         ="true"
      autostart   ="true">
      <log-server
         port    ="3000"
         capacity="2048" />
...
```

**AntTask.java**

```
public final class AntTask extends Task {

   private ...

   public void setLayout( String layout ) {
   }

   public void setGui( boolean gui ) {
   }

   public void setAutostart( boolean autostart ) {
   }

   public void addConfiguredLogServer( LogServer logServer ) {
   }

   @Override
   public void execute() {
      ...
   }
}
```

**Execution**

```
Buildfile: ...\build.xml
compile-sample:
run-client:

BUILD FAILED
...\build.xml:116: monitor-client doesn't support the nested "log-server" element.
```

**Question**

I search the applicable naming rules for elements and attributes and the mapping rules to Java language.

Comment: I found this which I think does what you want: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ant-dev/201009.mbox/%3CAANLkTinxcPuT2-re+MbNtnB+RskPM0yDfxjbc-edoTb6@mail.gmail.com%3E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer based on [matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/214790/matt) [comment](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ant-dev/201009.mbox/%3CAANLkTinxcPuT2-re+MbNtnB+RskPM0yDfxjbc-edoTb6@mail.gmail.com%3E), many thanks to him!

Apache ANT use two ways to identify element and attributes:

1. Reflection based on Java names, mapped in xml ignoring case as explain in the [manouti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1064245/manouti) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26842237/1624376).
2. Interfaces based. `org.apache.tools.ant.DynamicElement` and `org.apache.tools.ant.AttributeElement`

Interfaces must be used to map XML identifiers to Java identifiers when special characters are used, like hyphen, as shown below:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.DynamicElement;
import org.apache.tools.ant.Task;

public final class AntTask extends Task implements DynamicElement {

   private ...

   public void setLayout( String layout ) {
   }

   public void setGui( boolean gui ) {
   }

   @Override
   public Object createDynamicElement( String name ) {
      if( name.equals( "log-server" )) {
         return new Logserver();
      }
      return null;
   }

   ...

   @Override
   public void execute() {
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`org.apache.tools.ant.IntrospectionHelper`](http://api.dpml.net/ant/1.6.5/org/apache/tools/ant/IntrospectionHelper.html) is the class that does introspection to extract attributes from setter methods.

From the Javadocs of the constructor:

> `void setFoo(Bar)` is recognised as a method for setting the value of attribute `foo`, so long as `Bar` is non-void and is not an array type. Non-String parameter types always overload String parameter types, but that is the only guarantee made in terms of priority.

Comment: Thanks. I've check the method getPropertyName(): `methodName.substring(prefix.length()).toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH)`. I've understand that the problem isn't the method name but the mapping to XML. Since hyphen can't appear in Java identifier, it can't be used in XML.